# How to present Blue circle of current location in MKMapView iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an maps application in which I show the points of interest in the map using pins. I want to represent the current location with the blue circle which is shown in Google maps. Is there any way we can add it. Can any one please help me with this. I really appreciate your time.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the `setShowsUserLocation:` property of your map view to YES.  This can be done programmatically or in Interface Builder.  Be careful, as I believe the simulator still shows the user location in Cupertino, CA.

Also, if you continue tracking the user and their movements, the blue indicator will continue to move as they do.

Comment: In the simulator's Debug menu you can specify the location the simulator uses.

Answer (score 3):

You can get this by specifying `nil` in the appropriate delegate method:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation: (id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    if (annotation == mapView.userLocation) {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

This should cause `MKMapView` to use the default, which should be the blue circle.